# Автоматический запуск приложения

Tags: windows, delphi

Как сделать, чтобы программа сама запускалась при старте Windows?

Comment: Минусну, пожалуй. Очень боянистый вопрос и «!!!» с «???» зело раздражают,  а иконка «туда где часы» добавляется функцией `Shell_NotifyIcon`.

Comment: При чем здесь иконка в трэй? Речь об автозагрузке программы.

Comment: @Nofate, [эталон дельфи-бояна](http://www.podgoretsky.com/OtherParts/DD/dd.aspx) же, прямо из парижской палаты мер и весов.

Comment: ооо, очень антикварный сайт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реестр.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\run\` <- сюда добавить строковой индекс с путём к вашей программе.

Answer (score 3):

Можно, например:

- Создать ярлык в группе Главного меню "Автозагрузка".
- Прописаться в ветку реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` или `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` в зависимости от задачи.
- Сделать вашу программу службой.

---

UPD0. Кстати, да. Спасибо [[@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4)](/users/6679/karmadro4), что напомнил. Первые два варианта прокатывают только в том случае, если пользователь вошел в систему (все это связано с процессом winlogon). Для гарантированного автостарта при старте системы годится только служба.

Comment: Фактически, буквальному условию задачи удовлетворяет только вариант со службой.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, раз никто не предложил такого варианта, предложу я. Создать задачу в **планировщике заданий**. В качестве триггера старта выбрать "При запуске компьютера" (я так понимаю, это важно условие топик-стартера), тогда задача выполнится до winlogon'а, а в качестве самого задания - нужную программу.
В этом случае делать программу службой не нужно.